# How do I use promises in a Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, promise, extension-methods

What I am trying to do is create a chrome extension that creates new, nested, bookmark folders, using [promises](https://spring.io/understanding/javascript-promises).

The function to do this is *chrome.bookmarks.create()*.  However I cannot just
loop this function, because chrome.bookmarks.create is asynchronous.  I need to wait until the folder is created, and get its new ID, before going on to its children.

Promises seem to be the way to go.  Unfortunately I cannot find a minimal working example using an asynchronous call with its own callback like *chrome.bookmarks.create.*

I have read some tutorials [1](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/working-with-promises), [2](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises), [3](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises), [4](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).  I have searched stackOverflow but all the questions do not seem to be about plain vanilla promises with the chrome extension library.

I do not want to use a plugin or library: no node.js or jquery or Q or whatever.

I have tried following the examples in the tutorials but many things do not make sense.  For example, the tutorial states:

> The promise constructor takes one argument—a callback with two
>   parameters: resolve and reject.

But then I see examples like this:

> const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

How this works is a mystery to me.

Also, how can you call *resolve()* when its never been defined? No example in the tutorials seem to match real life code.  Another example is:

> ```
> function isUserTooYoung(id) {
>    return openDatabase() // returns a promise   
> .then(function(col) {return find(col, {'id': id});})
> ```

How do I pass in *col*, or get any results!

So if anyone can give me a minimal working example of promises with an asynchronous function with its own callback, it would be greatly appreciated.

SO wants code, so here is my non-working attempt:

```
//loop through all
function createBookmarks(nodes, parentid){  

  var jlen = nodes.length;
  var i;
  var node;
  for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++){
        var node = nodes[i];

        createBookmark(node, parentid);
  }
}

//singular create
function createBookmark(node, parentid){  
      var bookmark = { 
    parentId : parentid,
    index : node['index'],
    title : node['title'],
    url : node['url']
  }

  var callback = function(result){
    console.log("creation callback happened.");
    return result.id;  //pass ID to the callback, too
  }

    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        var newid = chrome.bookmarks.create(bookmark, callback)

      if (newid){
        console.log("Creating children with new id: " + newid);
        resolve( createBookmarks(bookmark.children, newid));
      }

    });
}

//allnodes already exists
createBookmarks(allnodes[0],"0");
```

Just doesn't work.  The result from the callback is always undefined, which it should be, and I do not see how a promise object changes anything.  I am equally mystified when I try to use promise.then().

```
var newid = promise.then(  //wait for a response?
            function(result){
            return chrome.bookmarks.create(bookmark, callback); 
            }
        ).catch(function(error){
            console.log("error " + error);
        });  

        if (node.children) createBookmarks(node.children, newid);
```

Again, newid is always undefined, because of course bookmarks.create() is asynchronous.

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: Chrome API methods that accept a callback don't have any returned value as you can see in the documentation. They provide the result only in the callback. BTW, you can simply use [Mozilla's polyfill for Chrome](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Honestly, you should just use the [web extension polyfill](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill). Manually promisifying the chrome APIs is a waste of time and error prone.

If you're absolutely insistent, this is an example of how you'd promisify **chrome.bookmarks.create**. For other chrome.* APIs, you also have to reject the callback's error argument.

```js
function createBookmark(bookmark) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    try {
      chrome.bookmarks.create(bookmark, function (result) {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) reject(chrome.runtime.lastError)
        else resolve(result)
      })
    } catch (error) {
      reject(error)
    }
  })
}


createBookmark({})
  .then(function (result) {
     console.log(result)
   }).catch(function (error) {
     console.log(error)
   })
```

To create multiple bookmarks, you could then:

```js
function createBookmarks(bookmarks) {
  return Promise.all(
    bookmarks.map(function (bookmark) {
      return createBookmark(bookmark)
    })
  )
}

createBookmarks([{}, {}, {}, {}])
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error)
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Take the advantage of the convention that the callback function always be the last argument, I use a simple helper function to promisify the chrome API:

```js
function toPromise(api) {
  return (...args) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      api(...args, resolve);
    });
  };
}
```

and use it like:

```js
toPromise(chrome.bookmarks.create)(bookmark).then(...);
```

In my use case, it just works most of the time.

Comment: I've tried pasting this in with `getTree` instead of `create` and `[0]` instead of `bookmark` (or remove bookmark and place the 0 in brackets after getTree) and it just says that nothing is found ... or it literally does nothing if I remove the `.then` entirely. Even with a console.log in the `return new Promise` I get nowt. What am I doing wrong? (am over at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72454215/how-do-i-get-chrome-bookmarks-to-provide-the-entire-tree-in-json)