# How to wait for the chrome.tabs.query to return tab id

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to handle the `chrome.tabs.query` to return tab id.

```
function getTabID () {
  var tabID = ''
  chrome.tabs.query({
    active: true,
  }, function(tabs) {
    tabsID = tabs[0].id
  } 
  return tabID
}
```

And i am trying to get the tabID. It seems `chrome.tabs.query({` is a async method.

```
var responseTabID = getTabID()     //calling the getTabID method.
// Code using responseTabID
```

So here i need to wait for the getTabID method to return the tabID. so that i am going to use that tabID further.

I can even call a method inside `function(tabs) { // calling a method here }`. But i need the tabID in multiple places, so i just wanted to implement a new method to return the tabID.

How to wait for the getTabID method? is it possible to using async/await?

Comment: You can use Promise or callbacks, see [How do I use promises in a Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50845092).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try wrapping your callback in promise and then use await inside an async function to retrieve the tab id:-

```
function getTabID() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            chrome.tabs.query({
                active: true,
            }, function (tabs) {
                resolve(tabs[0].id);
            })
        } catch (e) {
            reject(e);
        }
    })
}

//function where you need it
async function something() {
    let responseTabID = await getTabID();
}
```

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for suggesting that. If you feel like it can be improved, please do so.

Comment: @wOxxOm Did it. Hopefully this looks fine.